# call a function in export django

Tags: python, django, export

I have this in my models.py of Requests

```
@property
def calculate_pd_days(self):
    from reports.models import PdReport

    pd_report = (
        PdReport.objects.filter(
            request=self, maturity_date__lte=datetime.date.today()
        )
        .exclude(status=PdReport.Status.SUCCESS)
        .last()
    )
    if pd_report:
        pd_days = (datetime.date.today() - pd_report.maturity_date).days
        self.pd_days = pd_days
        return pd_days
    return 0
```

here is the export which I have in my views.py of reports

```
    def export_report_csv(request):
        
        print("Downloading reports")
        query_kwargs = {}
    
        reports = DataReportExcel.objects.annotate(
            full_name=Concat(
                "request__customer__first_name", Value(" "), "request__customer__last_name"
            ),
            broker_full_name=Concat(
                "request__broker__first_name", Value(" "), "request__broker__last_name"
            ),
            team_leader_full_name=Concat(
                "request__team_leader__first_name",
                Value(" "),
                "request__team_leader__last_name",
            ),
        ).filter(**query_kwargs)
    
        if request.user.role == "Team Leader":
            reporting_brokers = InternalUser.objects.filter(
                reporting_to=request.user.internaluser.pk
            )
            reports = reports.filter(
                Q(request__broker__in=reporting_brokers)
                | Q(request__broker=request.user)
                | Q(request__successior_broker=request.user.internaluser)
            )
    
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
        response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="DataReport.csv"'
    
        writer = csv.writer(response)
    
        writer.writerow(
            [
                "Pd Days",
            ]
        )
        datas = reports.values_list(
            "request__pd_days",
        )
    
        for i in datas:
            report_list = list(i)
            report_list[6] = report_list[6] + "'" if report_list[6] is not None else ""
            writer.writerow(report_list)
        return response
```

Now on export, I do not need to call this anymore request_pd_days, but I need to call the value that comes from the function calculate_pd_days in models.py of Requestz

How can I achieve that (tried with request__calculate_pd_days) but it says that cannot resolve keyword 'calculate_pd_days' into field.

Answer (score 0):

you save the return value also in `self.pd_days = pd_days` so you could access it as `request.pd_days`